# Scan text from a txt file in Java and throw the part I don't want

Tags: java, split

Say I have a text file looks like this:

```
"CarInLot KLM456 ND Meter4 120

 CarInLot VMK123 ME Moving 0

 CarInLot DKC003 WA Meter5 30

 Meter1 None 10

 Meter2 None 0

 Meter3 None 2

 Meter4 Yes 12"
```

Then I use

```
while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
     // Read the next name.
     String friendName = inputFile.nextLine();

     String[] tokens = friendName.split(" ");
  }
```

to split it, but I want the lines start with CarInLot in class Car and the lines start with Meter in class Meter. 
How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Check the first token and compare it with the terms you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop, iterate over the tokens and do something like this:

```
if (token[0].equals("CarInLot"))
{
    // do something

    // e.g. storing the variables
    // store token[i+1]
    // store token[i+2]
    // Etc..
} else if (token[0].equals("Meter"))
{
    // do something

    // e.g. storing the variables
    // store token[i+1]
    // store token[i+2]
    // Etc..
}
```

You can store the values in an `ArrayList` or just a (2D?) `array` or something likewise...

Comment: An `else if` would be appropriate in this situation.  Also why index `i` instead of `0`?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: I was already correcting :) thanks for being sharp

Answer (score 0):

Make constructors for each object that accept each piece of data as an argument.  Then check the first index of the `[]` to determine which type of object to create.  Create the object and add them to a `List` of the appropriate type.

```
List<Meter> meters = new ArrayList<Meter>();
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{   
     String[] tokens = inputFile.nextLine().split(" ");

     if(tokens[0].equals("CarInLot")){
        cars.add(new Car(tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4]));
     }else if(tokens[0].equals("Meter")){
        meters.add(new Meter(tokens[1], tokens[2]));
     }
}
```